# Efficient way to cluster colors using K-Nearest

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, machine-learning

I am trying to cluster colors on an image to a predefined classes (black, white, blue, green, red). I'm using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

src = cv2.imread('objects.png')

colors = np.array([[0x00, 0x00, 0x00],
                   [0xff, 0xff, 0xff],
                   [0xff, 0x00, 0x00],
                   [0x00, 0xff, 0x00],
                   [0x00, 0x00, 0xff]], dtype=np.float32)
classes = np.array([[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]], np.float32)
dst = np.zeros(src.shape, np.float32)

knn = cv2.KNearest()
knn.train(colors, classes)

# This loop is very inefficient!
for i in range(0, src.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, src.shape[1]):
        sample = np.reshape(src[i,j], (-1,3)).astype(np.float32)
        retval, result, neighbors, dist = knn.find_nearest(sample, 1)
        dst[i,j] = colors[result[0,0]]

cv2.imshow('src', src)
cv2.imshow('dst', dst)
cv2.waitKey()
```

The code works well and result is shown below. The image on the left is the input and the image on the right is the output.

[image: src] [image: dst]

However the loop above is very inefficient and make the conversion slow. What is the most efficient Numpy operation to replace the loop above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to remove the loop using the code below. The code runs very fast, almost similar with the C++ version.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

src = cv2.imread('objects.png')
src_flatten = np.reshape(np.ravel(src, 'C'), (-1, 3))
dst = np.zeros(src.shape, np.float32)

colors = np.array([[0x00, 0x00, 0x00],
                   [0xff, 0xff, 0xff],
                   [0xff, 0x00, 0x00],
                   [0x00, 0xff, 0x00],
                   [0x00, 0x00, 0xff]], dtype=np.float32)
classes = np.array([[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]], np.float32)

knn = cv2.KNearest()
knn.train(colors, classes)
retval, result, neighbors, dist = knn.find_nearest(src_flatten.astype(np.float32), 1)

dst = colors[np.ravel(result, 'C').astype(np.uint8)]
dst = dst.reshape(src.shape).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imshow('src', src)
cv2.imshow('dst', dst)
cv2.waitKey()
```

The code generated the correct result as before, with faster execution time.

[image: src] [image: dst]

Answer (score 2):

If you want a simple squared difference measure ("which is the euclidian nearest number), this will work.

Calculate differences

```
diff = ((src[:,:,:,None] - colors.T)**2).sum(axis=2)
```

(assuming `src` is y,x,3 in shape)

Pick closest colour index:

```
index = diff.argmin(axis=2)
```

New image:

```
out = colors[index]
```

If your colours are really to have component values of 0 or 0xff, you can use something like

```
out = np.where(src>0x88, 0xff, 0)
```

Comment: The latter suggestion will also get you all 8 colour combinations of 0xff and 0, like (0xff, 0xff, 0), not just the five you specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a look up table. So that you know corresponding class for each color. It doesn't have to be 256x256x256 you can reduce number of bins.